# Build fail issue in integration of GraphQL in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Steps i have followed:

1. SDK integrated using SPM https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-ios.git
2. Created a folder GraphQL --> schema.json
3. Added run script and added this code in that script

```
DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE="${BUILD_ROOT}"

while ! [ -d "${DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE}/SourcePackages" ]; do
  if [ "${DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE}" = / ]; then
    echo >&2 "error: Unable to locate SourcePackages directory from BUILD_ROOT: '${BUILD_ROOT}'"
    exit 1
  fi

  DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE="$(dirname "${DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE}")"
done

# Grab a reference to the directory where scripts are checked out
SCRIPT_PATH="${DERIVED_DATA_CANDIDATE}/SourcePackages/checkouts/apollo-ios/scripts"

if [ -z "${SCRIPT_PATH}" ]; then
    echo >&2 "error: Couldn't find the CLI script in your checked out SPM packages; make sure to add the framework to your project."
    exit 1
fi

cd "${SRCROOT}/${TARGET_NAME}"

# Declare your endpoint
GRAPHQL_SCHEMA_ENDPOINT="https://beta.pokeapi.co/graphql/v1beta" 
# Declare your file location
GRAPHQL_SCHEMA_FILE_LOCATION="GraphQL/schema.json"
#Run Your Script
"${SCRIPT_PATH}"/run-bundled-codegen.sh schema:download --endpoint="${GRAPHQL_SCHEMA_ENDPOINT}" "${GRAPHQL_SCHEMA_FILE_LOCATION}"
```

4. Build project

here iam getting build error

Can some one guide me the steps one by one how to integrate Apollo GraphQL. I feel the existing blogs not provided step by step process.

Comment: please share the error you get